# Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 not registered

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, oledb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   ["The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine"…DNN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201918/the-microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)
>    [AccessProviders working on WebDevelopment Server but not on IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352904/accessproviders-working-on-webdevelopment-server-but-not-on-iis7)

I have an ASP.NET 2.0 hosted on IIS 7.0 (Windows Server 2008). This application use an Access database (2000), it's an mde file. On my dev computer no problem. When I try to host I get this error : *"The Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registred on the local machine*

On the server, I have in \Windows\SysWOW64 the file msjet40.dll version 4.00.9756.0

What can I do to solve this problem ?

Thanks,

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201918/the-microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jet does not work on 64 bit machines, read other similar questions here in SO and you will find alternatives and suggestions :)

[Jet on x64 machines](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jet%2064)

Comment: Strange my dev machine is a x64 and no problem, normal ?

Comment: is the app pool in the dev machine configured to run in x32 mode?